# Error using select statement in psql command

Tags: postgresql, psql

I try to perform follow command

```
psql -c '\\COPY (SELECT file_name, status, reported, operator_id, load_dt AT TIME ZONE GMT FROM mytable) TO STDOUT' > myfile
```

I receive an error

> ERROR:  column "gmt" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...atus, reported, operator_id, load_dt AT TIME ZONE GMT FROM p...

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? copy/export table content to file?

Comment: Export table to csv with some changes

Comment: Time  zone names are text, try `at time zone 'GMT'`

Answer (score 1):

Can this be of help for you? This is on windows machine. Consider that query command might need modification, depending of what your PC operating system is.

`psql -U postgres -d aambackend_dev -c "SELECT \"createdAt\"::timestamp without time zone FROM \"User\" limit(2)" -H -o "D:\xxx1.html"`

- -U postgres - user
- -d typeorm - my database to which i want to connect
- -c ... - my query command
- -H format html, -o output file

For more info you can refer to: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html

Note 1: depending of column i want to select, for majority of columns i don't need escape backslash character. Only for columns of type timestamp with/out time zone i needed to add backslash for quotes.

Note 2: semicolon at the end was not needed in this case (in some other commands and cases it is necessary)

This is my exported file: [image]

If you wish CSV format:
`psql -U postgres -d aambackend_dev -c "SELECT "email",\"createdAt\"::timestamp without time zone FROM \"User\" limit(2)" -o "D:\xx2212.csv"`[image]